# ONly in IE:HTML5 audio tag giving MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED when same audio is played more than once

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-audio

I am using audio tag to play songs in my web page. Everything is working fine in chrome and firefox. But in IE I am observing following issue.

- any audio plays first time. But give error4:MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED if any audio is played after that including already played audio.
- I have more than 5 audio in the page
- audio src is set dynamical from url coming from server . 
  -audio load is called before play();
- html5 doctype is added in webpage

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I Solved the Issue by using Audio Object in JavaScript instead of using audio tag in html.
eg: var aud = new Audio();
    aur.src = audioUrl;
    aud.load();
```